# Need example to downsample plots with Bokeh

Tags: javascript, python, charts, bokeh, downsampling

I'm relatively new on Python and Bokeh technology. My goal is actually to be able to display line charts containing millions of points (like around 5 millions) in a browser. I'm conscient that actual browsers can't handle such an amount of data. This is why I'm trying to implement a downsampling algorithm to adapt the amount of points according to the user zoom.

Bokeh technology seems to be the technology I need. Indeed, I saw the following video on YouTube which presents a downsampling example which works perfectly : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPknmEwQ3Rc

That's what I want to implement for my project. So I read a lot of the User guide in the Bokeh website but the section for downsampling is empty and documentation doesn't seem complete to help me : http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/server.html#downsampling-with-server

I read some posts on Internet like on GitHub and some people talk about Bokeh examples for downsampling using `bokeh-server`. Unfortunately, I'm not able to recover any of this examples on Internet. All links I found were invalid. This is why I'm posting here. I would like to know if anybody would have a working project of downsampling using Bokeh or a link to share.

Thank you in advance !